# Как сделать валидацию для Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Вот *ViewModel* моего View1:

**View1VM.cs**

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
    {
        public class View1VM
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Выберите предмет")]
            public string Subject { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**View1.cshtml**

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.View1VM

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "View1";
    }

    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

            <p>
                Предмет: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Subject, new[]
                    {
                          new SelectListItem() { Text = "русский язык", Value = "1" },
                          new SelectListItem() { Text = "математика", Value = "2" },
                          new SelectListItem() { Text = "физика", Value = "3"},    
                    }, "выберите предмет...")
            </p>            

    </body>
```

То есть как вы наверное уже поняли необходимо, чтобы пользователь обязательно выбрал предмет. Сейчас этого ничего нет хоть я и установил атрибут `Required` для свойства `Subject`. Как дописать код для правильного функционирования?

Comment: Скопировал ваш код в новый проект. Серверная валидация отработала правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы возможно хотите клиентскую валидацию, об этом нельзя написать коротко, процетрую вкрадце [эту статью](http://smarly.net/asp-net-mvc-4-in-action/working-with-asp-net-mvc/validation/client-side-validation), но лучше прочесть ее полностью.

Необходимо это делать с помощью js, по сути я делал с помощью [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Подключаем:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

разрешаем валидацию в web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

используем как то так:

```
@Html.EnableClientValidation()
@Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript()
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home")) {
  @Html.EditorForModel()
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```